# C++ Hiding an Input Whilst its Being Typed in Windows Console

Tags: c++, windows, wordle-game

I'm pretty new to C++, and I'm trying to code a Wordle-like game, for 2 players using Visual Studio, to run in the windows cmd.

I want the user string input to be replaced with a '' or '*' character/symbol whilst it's being typed. I want to do this only using iostream, I have come across various solutions online, but none without importing any additional libraries (the solutions online usually use getch(), which needs an additional library)

My relevant (pretty bare) code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char a[5];
string str;

int main()
{
    cout << "\nSet your Wordle first: ";
    cin >> str;

    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        a[x] = str[x];
    }
return 0;
}
```

So I guess, as characters for 'str' are being typed, a '*' would be outputted on the windows console instead.

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: `I want to do this only using iostream` You cannot. C++ I/O streams simply don't support the necessary terminal control that you would need.

Comment: *but none without importing any additional libraries* That's because C++ has no knowledge of 'console'. It only has streams of characters. If you want to control the cosole that is used, you need an external library.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Scroll down for updated code.

There is no way of achieving this without using external libraries. However, the closest you can achieve is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

// Positions the cursor 'home'. Visually clears the screen. Using this to avoid flickering
void cls() 
{
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), COORD());
}

void input(std::string& str) // Asks the user for the word
{
    int char_count = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        cls();
        std::cout << "Set your Wordle first: ";

        for (int i = 0; i < char_count; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "*";
        }

        if (_kbhit())
        {
            char c = _getch();
            if (c == '\r') // The character '\r' means enter
            {
                return;
            }

            char_count++;
            str.push_back(c);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char a[5]{};
    std::string str;

    input(str);

    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) // Constrain to 5 characters
    {
        if (x < str.size()) a[x] = str[x];
        else break;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl; // Debug start
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); i++)
    {
        std::cout << a[i];
    } // Debug end
}
```

This code works as you wanted. You may see the mouse flickering but as I said, there is no proper way to do this in C++. Also, this is not the complete wordle game, and the code between // Debug start and // Debug end is just for testing purposes.

**Edit:** I played around with it and fixed the blinking issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int prev_char_count = 0;

// Positions the cursor 'home'. Visually clears the screen. Using this to avoid flickering
void cls()
{
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), COORD());
}

void input(std::string& str) // Asks the user for the word
{
    int char_count = 0;

    cls();
    std::cout << "Set your Wordle first: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < char_count; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "*";
    }

    while (true)
    {
        if (_kbhit())
        {
            cls();
            std::cout << "Set your Wordle first: ";

            char c = _getch();
            if (c == '\r') // The character '\r' means enter
            {
                return;
            }

            char_count++;
            str.push_back(c);

            for (int i = 0; i < char_count; i++)
            {
                std::cout << "*";
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char a[5]{};
    std::string str;

    input(str);

    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) // Constrain to 5 characters
    {
        if (x < str.size()) a[x] = str[x];
        else break;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl; // Debug start
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); i++)
    {
        std::cout << a[i];
    } // Debug end
}
```